# Formatting date and time to get date, month, year each in seperate var

Tags: php, date, datetime

In my json response of twitter API I get time stamp like this

```
Thu Mar 13 14:24:13 +0000 2014
```

I tried to format in this way:

```
$created_at = $thing->created_at;
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d H:m:s O Y', $created_at); 
echo $created_at;
echo $date->format('H:m:s');
```

Which gives result like this:

```
Thu Mar 13 14:24:13 +0000 2014
2015:12:13 //formated result. How come 2015?????
Wed Mar 12 14:18:14 +0000 2014
2015:06:12
Tue Jan 21 12:50:17 +0000 2014
2018:02:21
Thu Dec 12 09:29:16 +0000 2013
2015:05:12
```

Why giving wrong result?

I want to get month, year in seperate variable.

Comment: Um.. This works as expected: http://3v4l.org/RdcTH

Comment: @Leri For PHP 5.3 `14:12:13` is not the correct output, should be 14:24:13

Comment: @drew010 For php 5.3 it does not work at all. :)

Comment: @Leri So true, for 5.3.3 - 5.6 I mean :)

Comment: Instead of `->format('H:m:s'); ` use `->format('H:i:s');` if you don't need month number between hours and seconds...

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the creation of the `DateTime` by doing this:

```
$dt = new DateTime('@' . strtotime('Thu Mar 13 14:24:13 +0000 2014'));
```

This parses the date string to a Unix timestamp, and then creates a DateTime object.

```
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');  // yields the correct result.
```

Comment: Bad idea to use strtotime() like this. If `strtotime()` can parse datetime, so can `DateTime`, like: `$dt = new DateTime('Thu Mar 13 14:24:13 +0000 2014');`. And in your case, if timezone is set to anyoher than UTC, your DateTime object will always be in UTC, where maybe OP wishes to preserve timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

You are using month format character `m` instead of minutes `i`, thats why you get "wrong" output.

```
$dt = new DateTime('Thu Mar 13 14:24:13 +0000 2014');
echo $dt->format('H:i:s');
```